# Error message ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, ... '' in executing plt.fill_between

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd
import statistics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'Server=LAPTOP-34VQMBK6\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=Portofolio Data Analytics;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM vCanada2', conn)

display(df)
print(type(df))
df['NumOfImm'] = df['NumOfImm'].astype('Int64')

df = df.groupby('Year').agg({'NumOfImm': sum}).rename(columns={'NumOfImm': 'Number of Immigrants'}).reset_index()

x = df['Year'].astype('Int64').values
y1 = df['Number of Immigrants'].values

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20,8), dpi= 120)
plt.fill_between(x, y1=y1, y2=-y1, alpha=0.5, linewidth=2, color='seagreen')
plt.ylim(-280000, 280000)
plt.title('Immigration Rate in Canda (Two Side View)', fontsize=16)
plt.hlines(y=0, xmin=np.min(df['Year']), xmax=np.max(df['Year']), linewidth=.5)
plt.show()
```

I got some issues in executing plt.fill_between and the error message appeared "ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''". I have convert the 'Year' dtype into Int64 but it still not worked. Anyone know how to overcome this? thanks in advance.

Here it is the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-d40a8b7cf8e6> in <module>
      3 
      4 fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20,8), dpi= 120)
----> 5 plt.fill_between(x, y1=y1, y2=-y1, alpha=0.5, linewidth=2, color='seagreen')
      6 plt.ylim(-280000, 280000)
      7 plt.title('Immigration Rate in Canda (Two Side View)', fontsize=16)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in fill_between(x, y1, y2, where, interpolate, step, data, **kwargs)
   2541         x, y1, y2=0, where=None, interpolate=False, step=None, *,
   2542         data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2543     return gca().fill_between(
   2544         x, y1, y2=y2, where=where, interpolate=interpolate, step=step,
   2545         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1410     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1411         if data is None:
-> 1412             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1413 
   1414         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in fill_between(self, x, y1, y2, where, interpolate, step, **kwargs)
   5250     def fill_between(self, x, y1, y2=0, where=None, interpolate=False,
   5251                      step=None, **kwargs):
-> 5252         return self._fill_between_x_or_y(
   5253             "x", x, y1, y2,
   5254             where=where, interpolate=interpolate, step=step, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in _fill_between_x_or_y(self, ind_dir, ind, dep1, dep2, where, interpolate, step, **kwargs)
   5155 
   5156         # Handle united data, such as dates
-> 5157         ind, dep1, dep2 = map(
   5158             ma.masked_invalid, self._process_unit_info(
   5159                 [(ind_dir, ind), (dep_dir, dep1), (dep_dir, dep2)], kwargs))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py in masked_invalid(a, copy)
   2364         cls = type(a)
   2365     else:
-> 2366         condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))
   2367         cls = MaskedArray
   2368     result = a.view(cls)

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: what about if you use `astype(int)`?  Also, it would be helpful to paste the full error including stack trace.

Comment: `Int64` This is the nullable integer type, right? What happens if you use the non-nullable version, `int`?

Comment: @Riley I've tried it and resulting a blank figure

Comment: @NickODell I've tried it and resulting a blank figure

Comment: whats the result of `df.dtypes`?

Comment: @Riley I've figured it out, it be must using datetime dtypes rather than using int type